# Edit wars over tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, editing

Occasionally I'll run into users, usually new ones, who don't understand what certain tags mean (for example, marking a high-school-level Euclidean geometry question with 'differential-geometry'). Usually this isn't a problem; I change the tags, and that's the end of it. At the moment, I'm dealing with a question where the user insists on adding a completely inapplicable tag to the question and repeatedly reverts my edits. I've added a comment to that effect, but it was dismissed, and the edits continue. If the user insists on using an incorrect tag, is there anything further I can do, or this is an instance where I just have to walk away?

Comment: You can always flag a question for moderator attention (although having looked at the question under discussion, I suspect that in this case no moderator would take any action).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't engage in edit wars.

If your help with tagging is not appreciated, it's easy to find another place where it will be.

And [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1025398/) is not so clear cut. A circle is a smooth manifold. Rouché's theorem is an argument by smooth homotopy. The author mentions that more general degree theory facts may be used, and so tagged with [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry) and [differential-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-topology). Yes, it's a stretch; and yes, a retag was appropriate. But a forceful retag after the author's rollback was not.

As an aside, your comment

> differential geometry (the study of Riemannian metrics on manifolds and associated invariants)

isn't a correct definition of *differential geometry* either.

Comment: Meh, it's a brief note about Riemannian geometry (my point was to contrast it with differential topology), and I didn't want to go into any details.